# Клонирую проект с Гита, npm_modules не ставятся

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, git, npm, .net-core

Клонирую проект ASP .Net Core. В проекте нет папки `node_modules`, но все требуемые пакеты прописаны в `package.json`. Мне говорят, что `Visual Studio` должна сама создать папку `node_modules` и всё туда скачать. Но этого не происходит! В итоге ставлю вручную, получается несколько криво.

Как сделать, чтобы VS сама поставила `node_modules`?

Comment: «Мне говорят» — кто говорит? Вот их и спросите

Answer (score 0):

Должен быть такой файлик `package.json`, в котором прописаны модули для установки с версиями. Заходите в корневую папку проекта и выполняете команду из терминала

```
npm install
```

Дальше побегут логи и в конце вы получите либо `Успех`, либо ошибку.

Открываете по новой `Android Studio` и нажимате `build`. Все

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос, ОП же прямо написал, что и так ставит вручную, но хотел бы этого избежать.

Comment: Как уже сказали выше, не такого ответа я ждал;] И команду 'npm install' надо выполнять не из корня проекта, а из папки ClientApp/npm_modules, созданной вручную. Но всё равно спасибо что приняли участие.

Comment: @Garp я к сожалению не понимаю "кривизны". [А вот это не вручную](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?view=vs-2022#npmInstallPackage)